# My amazon Lex ElicitSlot repeats prompt. How do I continue the flow?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

Food Order bot
I have a branching dialog if a user asks for cheese on their burger, the bot will ask what type of cheese, but then return to the first question in the bot and continue to repeat the process.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJYyi.jpg

Answer (score 3):

In the `ElicitSlot` `dialogAction` response from the Lambda function, you are currently only returning the "CheeseSlot" value. If you do not return the values for the other slots, Lex treats them as `null` and as you noticed, it is expected for the entire flow to start again since the slots are marked as "Required".

So, in the response from the Lambda function, return all slots that have been filled while resetting the "CheeseSlot" value.

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue.Does this mean that I have to return multiple values in slottoelicit?

Comment: @lakshmi No, you have to return only a single slot name in the `slotToElicit` parameter. The `slots` parameter would contain all the slot values already taken from the user which you **don't** want to reset.

Comment: @lakshmi did you find any solution. or could you please share your updated code. I have same problem and stuck in it. Could you please help?

Comment: @Tayyab I just created seperate intents for each slot instead of having multiple slots in one intent.

Comment: @lakshmi i don't think so it is a good approach. is it??

Comment: Using separate intents is not recommended since that will surely affect the bot intent matching logic and you'll also soon run into the maximum number of intents per bot limit of 100: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gl-limits.html#gl-limits-bots

Answer (score 0):

Turns out as complexity increases AMAZON.AlphaNumeric doesn't work well. I used AMAZON.Movie instead also custom regex slots types would work.